# How do you get a "This question may already have an answer here:" tag off of a question?

Tags: discussion

I assume this takes 10-20k rep to attach or remove such a link/comment? I've had this happen a couple of times now that in neither case was that link/comment accurate. It can be a real disservice to a clever question.

A 'surface browser' would stop reading at that point thinking the question redundant and go to the linked question without even knowing that the linked question and associated answers do not address the question at hand.

Comment: Reading the comments on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229942/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-never-disappears, it sounds like you might be the only person who could see that banner, and that it will go away if the close votes expire.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: @DVK -The question is 'How old is Q from Star Trek?' It's now marked as [duplicate] and your fingerprints are all over it bigdog.

Comment: Here's the link http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56185/how-old-is-q-from-star-trek

Comment: @Morgan: I checked that question before it was put on hold, and I never saw the “This question may already have an answer here” banner. (I did see the close votes near the bottom, but it was nowhere near as prominent. Perhaps >10k rep users with mod tools see something different, but I don’t think they’re usually “surface browsers”.)

Comment: @alexwlchan No, it only exists as a comment until the post actually gets closed.  Then the comment is deleted and the banner added to the top of the question once it is closed.  If the banner appeared at the top _before_ it was closed, I'm guessing only Morgan could see it...